# term Elastic query not finding hit for alphanumeric keyword texts

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, keyword

how would I use the term or terms elastic query in the below situation?

1. The mapping set for the field `paidagentnumber` is as below

   ```
   "paidagentnumber": {
     "type": "text",
     "fields": {
       "keyword": {
         "type": "keyword",
         "ignore_above": 256
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. `GET statements_full/statements/_search?q=paidagentnumber:"017M0"`
   is finding 80 records in the system
3. But the following `GET` is not getting any records

   ```
   GET statements_full/statements/_search
   {
     "query": {
       "term" : {"paidagentnumber":"017M0"} 
     }
   }
   ```
4. But

   ```
   GET statements_full/statements/_search
   {
     "query": {
       "term" : {"paidagentnumber":"21212"} 
     }
   }
   ```

   is finding hit results i.e. If the `paidagentnumber` field doesn't have alphabets in it (just numeric) the `term` query is finding a hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paidagentnumber` field is analyzed (since it is `"type": "text"`), and so it's contents will be lowercased by the analyzer. Term queries are not analyzed, they are used, [according to the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-term-query.html), to find "the **exact** term specified in the inverted index", and so this lowercasing analysis will not be applied to the query, thus the mismatch between the two. "017M0" is not an exact match for "017m0".

You have options here:

- Use a [query_string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). This is the same type of query the `q` param creates, so if that is working as you want, use that:

  ```
  "query": { 
    "query_string" : { 
      "query": "paidagentnumber:017M0" 
    } 
  }
  ```
- If you want to use term queries, use a keyword field. You've already created one here, so just search the `paidagentnumber.keyword` field, instead.

  ```
  "query": { 
    "term" : {
      "paidagentnumber.keyword": "017M0"
    } 
  }
  ```

  If you didn't really want any sort of text analysis on the paidagentnumber field in the first place, then you could, alernatively, eliminate the `text` type from it's definition:

  ```
  "paidagentnumber": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "ignore_above": 256
  }
  ```